# Raspberry Pi Zero LCD + Headphone jack + Volume control

Tags: gpio, display, pi-zero, audio-playback, lcd

Is it possible to add an LCD screen, a headphone jack, and a Rotary Encoder (for volume control) to a Raspberry Pi Zero W?

If so, how could I solder all this? Any useful links/tutorials are greatly appreciated.